# if(new Boolean("true") == new Boolean("true"))

Tags: c#, boolean

i'm new in c# and i was wondering why this code return "false"?

```
if(new Boolean("true") == new Boolean("true"))
    Console.WriteLine("true");
else
    Console.WriteLine("false");
```

How can I check it from the VS level? Please give me explanation, not the answer.

Comment: That doesn't compile...there's no such constructor. (Change `new Boolean` to `Boolean.Parse` and it works fine.)

Comment: how do you mean 'check it from the vs level'?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Boolean.Parse("true") == Boolean.Parse("true"))
    Console.WriteLine("true");
else
    Console.WriteLine("false");
```

There is no constructor on Boolean that takes a string.  I think what you are trying to do is parse a string into a boolean.  That's what the above code does.